# eigen: create Vector-like Replicate (access with one index, LinearAccessBit)

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I want to create an `Eigen::Replicate` object that can be accessed like a vector, i.e. with a single index. I got that to work with the fixed-size `replicate<Index,Index>()`, which I can't use in reality, the non-one factor is not a compile-time constant. It also works when manually creating a `Replicate` object, but I feel like I'm just overlooking the obvious way of using a `replicate` function to achieve this:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>

using namespace Eigen;

int main(){
    Vector3i v (3);
    v << 0,1,2;

    constexpr int nReplications {2};

    auto replDynamic { v.replicate(nReplications, 1) };
    /* with a dynamic replication, two indexes are required to access a coeff */
    std::cout << "5th entry: " << replDynamic(4,0) << '\n';
    
    auto replFixed { v.replicate<nReplications, 1>() };
    /* I want to use only one index, but I require the number of replications
     * in one dimension to be dynamic */
    std::cout << "5th entry: " << replFixed(4) << '\n';
    
    /* don't know how to access the VectorwiseOp variant */
//  auto replVector { v.replicate(nReplications) };
//  std::cout << "5th entry: " << replVector(4) << '\n';
    
    /* this function doesn't exist */
//  auto replDefined { v.replicate<Dynamic,1>(nReplications, 1) };
//  std::cout << "5th entry: " << replDefined(4) << '\n';
    
    /* I'd rather not define it manually (it's not the intended way), but it works */
    Replicate<Vector3i,Dynamic,1> replManual { v, nReplications, 1 };
    std::cout << "5th entry: " << replManual(4) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The [source code](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/Replicate_8h_source.html) shows `VectorwiseOp<...>::replicate(Index factor)` in line 134, which sounds like what I need, but I don't seem to be able to access it.
And a function such as `replicate<Index,Index>(Index,Index)` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding a `.reshaped()` after the `replicate(...)` call, the `ColsAtCompileTime` are set to 1, and therefore, the resulting object can be accessed like a vector:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>

using namespace Eigen;

int main(){
    Vector3i v (3);
    v << 0,1,2;

    constexpr int nReplications {2};
    
    auto replReshaped { v.replicate(nReplications, 1).reshaped() };
    std::cout << "5th entry: " << replReshaped(4) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I understand what you are asking, since a `Vector3i` is a one column `Eigen::Matrix`, you can get a `VectorwiseOp<...>` expression template from a `Vector3i` (say) by using the `colwise()` function and then call the one argument `replicate` with that.

That is,

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>

using namespace Eigen;

int main() {

    Vector3i v(3);
    v << 0, 1, 2;

    auto foo = v.colwise().replicate(2);

    std::cout << "5th entry: " << foo(4) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Note though that using type deduction on a expression template, or "pseudo expression" as they are called in the Eigen documentation, is generally a bad idea i.e. writing `Eigen::Matrix<int, 6, 1> foo = v.colwise().replicate(2)` is safer; the Eigen documentation mentions the issue [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html).

Comment: Well, from your answer it certainly looks like you understood my question :) I'm gonna hold out for a bit for an answer that gets by without a non-intuitive element such as calling ```colwise()``` on a column vector, but otherwise I'll test it and accept it.